# When script is being executed: "adb.exe: no devices/emulators found"

Tags: android, usb, adb

I have a .bat file with simple script, which enables usb tethering on my phone:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.TetherSettings
adb shell input keyevent 20
adb shell input keyevent 20
adb shell input keyevent 20
adb shell input keyevent 20
adb shell input keyevent 20
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ENTER
adb shell sleep 3
adb shell am force-stop com.android.settings
```

But when adb trying to execute two last commands I getting an error:

> adb.exe: no devices/emulators found

I don't know why that is a thing, so how can I fix it?

Comment: why are you sending the `force-stop` ?

Comment: I tried to send home button keyevent and got same thing.

Comment: It would be better if you explain what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I'm trying to enable USB Tethering on my phone through ADB, using user input simulation.

Comment: is you `adb` using the same USB?